# Atualizar Versão CakePHP para mais recente

Tags: php, cakephp

possuo um projeto em mãos com a versão do CakePhp 2.2.3, gostaria de atualizar para uma versão mais recente do framework, pois se nao me engano, já está na versão 3.5. Já vi alguns links na internet e não entendi muito bem, alguem poderia me dar uma direçao?

Answer (score 1):

O CakePHP mudou muito da versão 2.x para a versão 3.x. O código é incompatível, principalmente a parte de consulta dos dados (ORM) dele.

Os desenvolvedores do cakephp fizeram uma ferramenta para ajudar - https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade, mas ela não faz milagre, principalmente se o seu código for grande.

Interessante talvez seja migrar para a versão mais nova do cakephp 2, a versão 2.10. Ela precisa de poucos ajustes e traz muitas melhorias que foram incorporadas no cake 3.